# Laravel Validating Parent/Child User Input

Tags: php, laravel

I'm having a problem validating to prevent a user selecting a parent element, for example:

- Option 1
- Option 2

  - Sub Option 1
  - Sub Option 2
  - Sub Option 3
- Option 3

A user could select a top level option if it has no children, for example they could select option 1 and option 3, but they can't select option as they would need to select one of the sub options.

The database structure is:

id, parent_id, name

If the option has a parent, the parent_id is the id of the parent (if not it is null).

I'm currently validating to check if the option exists in the database, but this obviously doesn't prevent top level options being selected if they have children.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean blocking parent items in a select?

You can make a `children` function in your model, this is an hasMany relation ship. If the count is higher that 0 you item is selectable.

Or you can use baum(https://github.com/etrepat/baum) to check if the item is a "leave"(Item without children).

The validation of the input can be done with a custom validation rule(https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#custom-validation-rules).
Just get the input, check if there are children and return true or false.